# String handling in Swift 2

Tags: string, replace, swift2

I want to change a string using the following code:

```
    if let plistrange = newpath.rangeOfString(".plist") {
        print("plistrange:", plistrange)
        newpath = newpath.removeRange(plistrange)
        newpath = newpath + "_1.plist"
    }
```

the line with removeRange signals the error:
***cannot assign value of type '()' to 'String'***
 I do not understand this message nor what I have to do to make it run.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer is, that the newpath.removeRange does not return a string and hence writing the line as

```
newpath.removeRange(plistrange)
```

works fine.